# Is it correct to call saveEventually() after saveAllInBackground() throw exception in parse android?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am calling saveAllInBackground() as follow

```
 ParseObject.saveAllInBackground(Arrays.asList(item, user), new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e == null || handleError(e, Arrays.asList(item, user))) {
           //Update UI ...            
        }
    }
}
```

handle error is :

```
private boolean handleError(ParseException e, List<ParseObject> parseObjects) {

    boolean calledSaveEventually = false;

        if (e == null) return calledSaveEventually;

        int errCode = e.getCode();
        switch (errCode) {
            case ParseException.CONNECTION_FAILED :
            case ParseException.TIMEOUT:
                Utility.saveEventuallyAll(parseObjects);
                calledSaveEventually = true;
                break;
        }
        return calledSaveEventually;

}
```

Now Problem is if saveAllInBakground() Throw CONNECTION_FAILED exception then as code say I am calling saveEventually() and it worked perfectly but next time if I again call saveAllInBackground(by doing same action from UI without Network connection) then done(ParseException) method of saveCallback never called.

it is the bug in Parse android SDK or I am using it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling the Local Datastore?

`Parse.enableLocalDatastore();`